# $locatioChangeStart fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

basically, I'm trying to make some array which should have history of visited pages in my app.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {

    historyArray.push($location.path());

    console.log("history", historyArray);
});
```

at the begining it looks ok, I mean [ "/page1", "/page2"], but then it starts to multiply the "ChangeStart" effect to i.e. ["/page1", "/page2", "/page3", "/page3", "/page4", "/page4", "/page4"] etc.

any ideas how to prevent it?

edit. this is just an example, i need $locationChangeStart for some ngDialog modals and other complicated things, but I'm facing similar sutation (like opening 5 modals at the same time)

Comment: you can check if the page already exists within the array, and push only if it doesn't.

Comment: It depends on where do you add event listener. Do you put it in controllers?

Comment: Umidbek, nope, got it in service.

Comment: Service defines every time when it calls (`new Service`), so if this event listener runs in service constuctor, it will bind event to `$rootScope` every time when service is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a conditional to check if the location actually changed and an indexOf to make sure the page doesn't exist within the array.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {
        if(next !== current && historyArray.indexOf(current) === -1) {
            historyArray.push($location.path());
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: it didn't work - still the same situation. does it mean there are some 'bigger' issues somewhere else?